# Git Move 2 old commit to existed branch

Tags: git

I don't want to break something so I prefer ask here. I've accidentally make a feature on a branch for test, I try to move the commit to new branch and base them on master with `git rebase` but I put the 3 commit in the branch of the new feature like that:
`N = New feature`
`T = Test branch`
`M = Master`

```
M
|\
| T
N - T1 - T2 - N1
```

And I want get:

```
M
|\
| T - T1 - T2
N - N1
```

I've already try some rebase but in the origin I had only the branch Test with the three commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this problem apart: Duplicate the commits and remove them. You can't "move" directly.

First, duplicate two `T` commits to the `T` branch with `cherry-pick`. You can grab the SHA of the two commits you want to move, and then follow these steps

```
git checkout test
git cherry-pick <commit 1> <commit 2>
```

Then, delete them from the `N` branch

```
git checkout new
git rebase HEAD~4
```

Locate the two commits and delete them with the text editor that pops up from Git, and save the file and quit. Git will do the rest.